# Get minimal XPath of an element

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to create a function which returns **XPATH** of an element. Unfortunately it returns absolute xpath which is not enough.

I want to get as minimal xpath as possible (or better - more "clever", not necessarily minimal). For example, if element has id, then return xpath depended on its id.

I want to use this xpath multiple times and absolute xpath is very vulnerable according to page changes.

Or if it's parent has id, then return parents xpath by id and concat with `/child`.

Is it possible with `lxml` module or another module?

For example **XPath helper wizard** extension can do that better.

```
def _load_root(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    r.encoding = 'utf-8'
    html = r.content
    return etree.fromstring(html, etree.HTMLParser())

def get_xpath_by_text(text,url):
    root = _load_root(url)
    e = root.xpath('.//*[contains(text(),"{}")]'.format(text))
    print root.getpath(e)
```

> /html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tr[6]/td[2]/div[1]

Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for two contradictory things, as far as I can see: a minimal XPath, and an XPath that is stable against changes to the document.

The minimal XPath for an element is typically something like `(//*)[134]`, but this is very sensitive to document changes.

You can get an XPath relative to the nearest ancestor with an id() attribute using a recursive algorithm like:

```
function minimalXpath(Node node) {
  if (exists(node/@id))
    then "id(" + node/@id + ")"
  else if (node is root)
    then ""
  else minimalXPath(node.getParent()) + "/" + node.getName() +
    "[" + node.getSiblingPosition() + "]"
}
```

Comment: Thank you Michael for the answer. I found a term "minimal path" as closest to what I want to achieve. Your answer solves the problem with ids but there are much more situations. For example very common is class="price" or itemprop="price" etc. So I can't rely only on ids (it's the best option) because many times there are no ids but there are still better "anchors" than absolute path.